# Declare variable with loops

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to declare this variable. Like this

```
for (var a:int=1; a<=9; a++)
{
var ori_[a]_b1:Number = shuffledLetters[a].split("_")[0];
}
trace(ori_1_b1);
```

I tried like this, but did not succeed.

```
for (var a:int=1; a<=9; a++)
{
this["var ori_"+a+"_b1:Number"] = shuffledLetters[a].split("_")[0];
}
trace(ori_1_b1);
```

Thanks before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551998/set-dynamic-variable-name-in-actionscript-3-0 See this.

Comment: Typically when someone is trying to do something like this, they really just need to take a moment to learn how to utilize an Array or another type of collection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this["ori_"+a+"_b1"] = shuffledLetters[a].split("_")[0];
```

When you assign a property via created string, you only specify the name, not type.

Comment: for (var a:int=1; a<=9; a++)
{
this["var ori_"+a+"_b1"] = 1;
}
trace(ori_1_b1);
But Error... :(

Comment: Again, why is a "var" in the string? I say, leave ONLY the name, in this case, `ori_1_b1` inside brackets. `for (var a:int=1; a<=9; a++) { this["ori_"+a+"_b1"] = 1; } trace(ori_1_b1);`

Comment: hmmm, its changing the value, not create a variable with a unique name.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. The only thing is that it cannot declare variables in this fashion unless the class is dynamic. So if your class is not dynamic, you cannot do this (and there is no way to do what you want).